# How to read rssFeed xml using rome in gwt

Tags: gwt, rss, rome

Using rome I created the rssFeed xml and now I want to read that xml so that user can view  and user can view rss feed in google etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RPC feature in GWT to first send the `.rss` file to the server, upon which, its converted into your requirements and sent back to the client. You can use Apache Common's [Digester API](http://commons.apache.org/digester/) to extract various information from the `.rss` file in the Server.